# How to prevent memcache storing an incomplete page when someone clicks away prior to page load completion?

Tags: php, drupal, memcached, centos

I'm fairly new to memcache so apologies if this is an obvious one. I have looked through the memcached documentation and tried various Google searches but to no avail.

**The setup** :

- Drupal 6.19
- Memcache API and integration module
- Authcache module
- Centos 5
- Memcached 1.2.6

If you need further information let me know.

**The situation** :

Memcache is certainly running, bins are being filled and page load times are incredible. However, I noticed only recently, when doing some testing that when I clicked on a link before the page had finished loading memcache stores the current page state in memory. So, when the next user comes along he sees a half formed page that I was too impatient to wait for.

Your response might be to sort out my page loading - which I'm looking in to. But I would like to solve this one as well. This means that if a user with a particularly slow connection is the first one to visit a page then he / she might click away and store an incomplete page for everyone else to see.

I appreciate any advice you can offer. Even if it is pointing me to an obvious resource I've overlooked.

Thank  you

Answer (score 1):

Try `ignore_user_abort(true);` http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure this isn't a browser cache issue?  This doesn't sound like a memcached issue at all unless you've got a weird setup.

Comment: During testing, I viewed the page originally in Firefox - this is when I clicked early before the page had finished loading. Then, I viewed the same page in Camino (Mac browser) and saw the same incomplete page. With Memcached turned off the problem doesn't exist.

Comment: Viewing the page in Safari, where it hasn't been opened before, has the same result.

Comment: @mikeefreedom I guess I'm not understanding how the $cache->set method would get called before the content was completely generated.  It seems like if the page load is aborted, nothing would be set in the cache.  Am I just misunderstanding what you're doing?

Comment: Maybe you had a server-side glitch in your php that caused an incomplete result which was then cached?

Comment: I will look again through the Drupal and Memcache API code to try and find when it is writing to the cache. I would have thought it should have generated the entire page before it serves it to the browser but I could be wrong.